# html node is not getting appended

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, removechild

In the below program I am trying to append and remove child nodes to/from a parent node in html document.

I am trying to do this:

Once `Node 1` button is clicked, check if parent has child `node2`. If yes, remove `node2` child from parent. Then append `node1`.

My program works fine if `node2` is already present as a child. However, if `node2` is not already a `child` then `node1` does not get appended at all. Where am I going wrong ?

Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Nodes ...</h3>
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="func_node1()">Node 1</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="func_node2()">Node 2</button>
        <br/><hr/>
        <div id="display">
            <p id="p1"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        /*Create two nodes 'node1' and 'node2' with some text in them*/
        var node1 = document.createElement("p");
        var node1_text = document.createTextNode("ONE 1 NODE");
        node1.appendChild(node1_text);

        var node2 = document.createElement("p");
        var node2_text = document.createTextNode("TWO 2 NODE");
        node2.appendChild(node2_text);
        /*Issue in this function*/
        function func_node1()
        {
            var parent = document.getElementById("display"); 
            var children = parent.childNodes;
            var i;
            for(i=0; i<children.length; i++)
            {
                if(children.item(i).id == 'node2');
                {
                    parent.removeChild(node2);
                    break;
                }
            }
            parent = document.getElementById("display");
            parent.appendChild(node1);
            //document.write("CLEAR");
        }
        function func_node2()
        {
            var parent = document.getElementById("display");
            parent.appendChild(node2);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open the html page, then click on `Node 1` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon in this line

```
if (children[i].id == 'node2'); 
{
    ...
}
```

This will always execute the code, whether `node2` exists or not, but if you remove this then the code will not execute because `node2` does not have an id.

You need to set the `id` like this

```
node2.id = 'node2';
```

---

There is also an error in this line, as you are not referencing an element that has been appended.

```
parent.removeChild(node2);
```

It should look like this

```
parent.removeChild(children[i]);
```

---

Also, you define this in multiple places.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("display");
```

As the parent doesn't seem to change you can just define this at the beginning of the script and avoid querying the DOM when not necessary.

```js
/*Create two nodes 'node1' and 'node2' with some text in them*/
var parent = document.getElementById("display");

var node1 = document.createElement("p");
var node1_text = document.createTextNode("ONE 1 NODE");
node1.id = 'node1';
node1.appendChild(node1_text);

var node2 = document.createElement("p");
var node2_text = document.createTextNode("TWO 2 NODE");
node2.id = 'node2';
node2.appendChild(node2_text);
/*Issue in this function*/
function func_node1() {
    var children = parent.childNodes, i;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].id == 'node2') {
            parent.removeChild(children[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    parent.appendChild(node1);
}

function func_node2() {
    parent.appendChild(node2);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Nodes ...</h3>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="func_node1()">Node 1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="func_node2()">Node 2</button>
    <br/><hr/>
    <div id="display">
        <p id="p1"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This wont work , since node 2 is the newly created element, and it is not a part of DOM until you append it to the parent node. 
That's why it is giving you an error saying

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The
>   node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Now we will come to solution for it.

1. Before removing check weather the element is present or not. and remove it. 
   Rather than using removeChild(node) , better go with

> removeChild(document.getElementById("correspondingId"))

so that it removes it from DOM.

Hope the solution helped.